# Javascript for in loop not working for getting S3 pre-signed urls

Tags: javascript, express

I cannot get my code below to work.

I am querying for user object/s, then *for each* user object returned I need to get 2 pre-signed urls from its idKey and selfieKey property then send back the user objects with their respective pre-signed urls.

When trying to do this inside a for in loop I get [undefined, undefined] when logging the array keyArray so that code fails here before reaching the S3 method.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you

```
router.post("/api/verification/check", auth, async (req, res) => {
    try {
      const users = await User.find({ // Gets 1 or more User objects })

      let usersWithUrls = [] // add results for each loop iteration 

      for (const user in users) {
      
          const keyArray = [user.idKey, user.selfieKey]
          console.log(keyArray)
        
          const urlArray = await Promise.all(
            keyArray.map((key) =>
              S3.getSignedUrlPromise("getObject", {
                Bucket: "app-bucket",
                Key: key,
                Expires: 30,
              })
            )
          )
          const idUrl = urlArray[0]
          const selfieUrl = urlArray[1]

          usersWithUrls.push({ user, idUrl, selfieUrl })
      }

      if (users) {
        return res.send(usersWithUrls)
      }
    } catch (err) {
      res.status(400).send()
    }
  }
)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try changing your for in to a for of.

```
for (const user of users) {
```

for in loops gives you the index.

for of loops gives you the object